# Creating Clone Animations in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

batch.draw(icon[i].getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 1700,(screenHeight * (i / enemies.length)));I am trying to use a dynamic Array of Animations for the purpose of creating a number of Enemy Sprites in an RPG game. At the moment, I seem to be able to fit an atlas to an Animation array, but when I go to draw them, only one appears, though it is in the place that I described, so I believe that the others are being rendered but do not stay on the screen for some reason.
In my initialisation:

```
 spriteatlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet.atlas"));

    backgroundatlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("sprite.atlas"));

    //List<Animation> icon = new ArrayList<Animation>(enemies.length);
    icon = new Animation[enemies.length];
    for (int i =0;i<enemies.length;i++)
        icon[i] = new Animation(1/15f, spriteatlas.getRegions());
    background = new Animation(1/2f, backgroundatlas.getRegions());
```

In the draw

```
elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    batch.draw(background.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i<enemies.length;i++) {
       batch.draw(icon[i].getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 1700,(2*i*screenHeight/enemies.length*screenHeight));
    }
```

Thanks for that Johnathon, basic Math Errors are the Bane of my existence ( :/). Its still only rendering the one sprite though, is there any reason why it might do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(2*i*screenHeight/enemies.length*screenHeight));
```

probably doesn't do what you're thinking, if i = 0 (for the first enemy), assume screenHeight is something like 1000 and you have 16 enemies:

```
2*0*1000/16*1000 = 0
```

then when i = 1

```
2*1*1000/16*1000 = 125000
```

125000 on the y axis is wayyy off screen, I recommend taking off the last screenHeight, and maybe the first 2, because as soon as you exceed 1/2 of the enemies they will render off screen as well, so:

```
(i * screenHeight / (float) enemies.length);
```

and to make it even more readable

```
screenHeight * (i / (float) enemies.length);
```

which shows that you are scaling the screenHeight based on the number of enemies in the array

Comment: edited code to change that line, but I'm still getting the same rendered screen, one sprite is appearing at the correct x value, and that seems to be it. Are there any other errors that you can see?

Comment: This seems like it should work, maybe just output the value of enemies.length and screenHeight to the log and see if they're sain. couldn't hurt to see the value of `screenHeight * (i / enemies.length)` by outputting it within the loop as well

Comment: I edited the answer, you need to cast enemies.length to float since it returns an int

Comment: That's done it, changing to float seems to have done the trick. Strange though how it didn't throw an error, but I won't complain!

Comment: Oh it's not a throwable error is why, when dividing ints the decimal part is basically truncated, 15/16 is 0 and 16/15 is 1, however 15/16f is .9375. It's because floating point calculations are heavier than integer calculations and the interpreter will leave the result as an integer unless you specify otherwise. I realized now that adding the parenthesis to the line is the real cause, so to avoid a floating calculation you could once again rewrite this to `(screenHeight * i / enemies.length);` which evaulates to a large enough number to be divided by enemies.length and remain an interger.